# "npx tailwindcss" command sometimes stops working for apparently no reason in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tailwind-css

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC project with Visual Studio 2022 and I'm using Tailwind CSS but for some reason, the command "npx tailwindcss" used to build the css file for my project stops working periodically and I need to change it to "npx tailwind" to make it work again, and that command also stops working after some time. That's the first time I'm working with node.js and Tailwind, so I'm struggling to understand what's actually happen...

That's the code I have in my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hybriotheca.web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "css:build": "npx tailwindcss -i ./wwwroot/css/site.css -o ./wwwroot/css/styles.css --minify"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

And those are the parts of the .csproj that I believe are most relevant:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <UpToDateCheckBuilt Include="wwwroot/css/site.css" Set="Css" />
    <UpToDateCheckBuilt Include="tailwind.config.js" Set="Css" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Tailwind" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="npm run css:build" />
</Target>
```

I tried including "`<None Include="node_modules/**" />`" inside of the `ItemGroup` in the .csproj, but it didn't seem to do anything.

I've already searched online for anyone talking about this problem, but I didn't have any luck.